# React-Admin Filter+SearchInput has no effect when searching

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have the following filter component code:

```
import { Filter, SearchInput} from 'react-admin';

const CustomerFilter= props => (
    <Filter {...props}>
        <SearchInput source='id' resettable alwaysOn />
    </Filter>
);

export default CustomerFilter;
```

That's implemented here:

```
import CustomerFilter from './CustomerFilter';
[...]
return (
    <List {...props} filters={ <CustomerFilter /> }>
```

The result's UI is great - I can see a search bar at the top. Searching for it changes the URL, appending `?filter=%7B"id"` and such. However, the UI does not update: Only the URL I can see change. Even if I type `zzzzzz`.

Anything specific I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Network tab of your browser DevTools: you'll see that react-admin sends the `id` filter to your API. The way it sends this filter depends on your `dataProvider`, but for the `ra-data-simple-rest`, it looks like this:

> `GET https://path/to/my/api/foo?id=123`

It's your API's responsibility to use these query parameters to filter the result.